# Decision tree for selecting tests to monitor ML drift?

Tags: machine-learning, data-drift

I'm exploring concepts for monitoring drift and I have come up with the following decision tree:

[image]

| Criteria | Decision |
| --- | --- |
| Nature of Data Distribution | KS test is suitable for comparing continuous distributions. JSD for probability distribution comparisons. Chi-Squared test for categorical data analysis, especially when assessing independence or expected frequency comparisons within categories. |
| Sample Size | KS test is more stable with smaller sample sizes. JSD's performance improves with larger samples. Chi-Squared test might be less reliable with small samples, especially when expected frequencies are small in categorical data analysis. |
| Test Purpose and Interpretability | KS test provides a straightforward comparison of continuous distributions, while JSD and Chi-Squared test offer more nuanced insights into probability distributions or categorical relationships, respectively. |
| Statistical Assumptions | Non-Parametric Analysis: All tests, KS for simpler interpretation |

Have I over-looked any important factors?